# Classes in CoffeeScript

Tags: class, coffeescript, phantomjs

I have some code on CoffeeScript (run under PhantomJS):

```
class Loadtime
  constructor: ->
    @page = require('webpage').create()

  check: (uri) ->
    time = Date.now()
    @page.open uri, (status) ->
      console.log 'foo'
      if 'success' is status
        time = Date.now() - time
        return time
      else
        return "FAIL to load #{uri}"

loadtime = new Loadtime()
console.log loadtime.check('http://example.com') # undefined
phantom.exit()
```

Class have constructor and one public method.
Line `@page.open uri, (status) -> ...` must call callback function, but it does not call it (line `console.log 'foo'` does not execute).
Why?

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `phantom.exit` immediately, so it has no time to load the web page. Add a callback to your `check` function that you call at the end of the `open` callback, and call `phantom.exit` inside the callback passed to `check`:

```
class Loadtime
    constructor: ->
        @page = require('webpage').create()

    check: (uri, cb) ->
        # ...
        @page.open uri, (status) ->
            # ...
            cb()

loadtime = new Loadtime
loadtime.check 'http://www.example.com/', (time) ->
    console.log time
    process.exit()
```

Comment: Ok, thank you.  
Can you tell me how can I wait for the end of execution of function `@page.open uri` if I'll remove `phantom.exit()`?

Comment: @SergeyBlohin: You need to add an argument to `check` that you can pass a callback into and then modify your calling code to let it execute asynchronously. I've edited my answer to show more clearly what that might look like.